# Browsing folders with mouse is randomly slow, when using keyboard, it's fast

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, mouse

Running Win 8.1.

This problem is weird, I can't find anything about this happening with someone else.

Is there a way to disable the mouse driver somehow so that mouse still works or smth?

Using Logitech G700s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. Turns out there was the problem with file browsing software Clover (adds tabs to windows file explorer). Anyways I disabled it's feature  "Double click on folder margin to navigate up" from settings and the problem went away.